# User require.js in a non spa application

Tags: requirejs

I just learned of `require.js` in a SPA tutorial. I love the idea of loading related js files in a `require` statement.

But my current website is a Non-SPA, a hybrid with some server rendered pages which have asyncally changed data.

The SPA tutorial uses `require.js` library and it starts with a `main.js`. But if I have several pages, does it mean I will have multiple `main.js` for each of the web page?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example project that is a multi-page app:

https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage